# ScrollPane in TextArea Layout(null)

Tags: java

Here is part of my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class WindowTest {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

    private WindowTest() {
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        text.setBounds(20, 100, 320, 270);
        scroll.setVisible(true);
        window.add(scroll);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowTest().createWindow();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how to add scroll bar to TextArea "text". It's a database app and it sends String of data to TextArea. I want the app to show scrollbar (vertical or horizontal) if necessary - too many Strings in TextArea. I have been trying many things but nothing works. Layout has to be null because I made all components manually and I dont want to set everything from beginning (its only part of the code).

Comment: Have you tried calling `update()` or `revalidate()` on the `JScrollPane` itself? I don't know if that would help but something i would try first. Obviously after you add all the text to it.

Comment: You need to add the textarea to the scrollpane's viewportview. e.g. scroll.setViewportView(text);

Comment: @3kings: never needed in this situation due to Swing's MVC structure.

Comment: @Matthew: he's already doing that. When the component is passed into the JScrollPane's constructor, it is then added to the viewport as its view, as per the [JScrollPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane-java.awt.Component-).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  text.setBounds(20, 100, 320, 270);
> ```

Don't set bounds on the JTextArea component.  It needs to become larger to show the entire text.  The JScrollPane will then show a portion of the JTextArea.

---

*Update:*  also, use a suitable layout manager, don't use absolute positioning.

Corrected code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class WindowTest {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

    private WindowTest() {
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowTest().createWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistakes:

- You must set bounds of the scrollpane not the textarea.
- `window.setVisible(true);` this must be called at the end.
- You must set size of your JFrame.

Code below working for me.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class WindowTest {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

    private WindowTest() {
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        window.setLayout(null);

        scroll.setBounds(20, 100, 320, 270);
        window.add(scroll);

        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowTest().createWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to set bounds on the scrollpane, nor to explicitly set it to visible.  It will automatically be visible when its parent is made visible, and using a layout manager is better than absolute positioning.  *(PS. I missed the absolute positioning in the original question)*

Comment: yes i missed that part, setVisible is not necessary.